# How to embed pic_timing SEI wallclock timecodes in RTMP streaming?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, rtmp

I need to stream my desktop to the AWS MediaLive service and, as a requirement, I must include wallclock timecodes in the stream. The AWS support kindly informed me that for h.264 encoded streams, I need to provide timecodes as "pic_timing SEI messages".

I'm streaming with FFmpeg via the RTMP protocol on Windows 10 so, I tried adding the `use_wallclock_as_timestamps` and `copyts` flags to my command.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -show_region 1 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i desktop -vf scale=320:240 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -copyts -f flv rtmp://<ip>:1935/<app>/<stream>
```

However, the timecodes are not picked up by AWS MediaLive.

My questions are:

- Does the `use_wallclock_as_timestamps` flag actually create timecodes as "pic_timing SEI messages" as required?
- If not, how do I add wallclock timecodes as "pic_timing SEI messages"? It doesn't have to be every frame. Every 2 or 3 seconds would suffice.

I'm stumped. I couldn't find the answer in the FFmpeg documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The encoder (x264) has to write these. I'll check.

Comment: Thank you @Gyan, any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "pic_timing SEI messages" support, the following encoder wrappers for H.264/AVC have this implemented in `ffmpeg`:

1. `h264_qsv`
2. `h264_vaapi`
3. `h264_nvenc`

You can confirm support for the same via:

(a). For the `h264_vaapi` encoder wrapper (Available on Linux only):

```bash
ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_vaapi

Encoder h264_vaapi [H.264/AVC (VAAPI)]:
    General capabilities: delay hardware 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: vaapi 
    Supported pixel formats: vaapi_vld
h264_vaapi AVOptions:
  -low_power         <boolean>    E..V....... Use low-power encoding mode (only available on some platforms; may not support all encoding features) (default false)
  -idr_interval      <int>        E..V....... Distance (in I-frames) between IDR frames (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -b_depth           <int>        E..V....... Maximum B-frame reference depth (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 1)
  -rc_mode           <int>        E..V....... Set rate control mode (from 0 to 6) (default auto)
     auto            0            E..V....... Choose mode automatically based on other parameters
     CQP             1            E..V....... Constant-quality
     CBR             2            E..V....... Constant-bitrate
     VBR             3            E..V....... Variable-bitrate
     ICQ             4            E..V....... Intelligent constant-quality
     QVBR            5            E..V....... Quality-defined variable-bitrate
     AVBR            6            E..V....... Average variable-bitrate
  -qp                <int>        E..V....... Constant QP (for P-frames; scaled by qfactor/qoffset for I/B) (from 0 to 52) (default 0)
  -quality           <int>        E..V....... Set encode quality (trades off against speed, higher is faster) (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  -coder             <int>        E..V....... Entropy coder type (from 0 to 1) (default cabac)
     cavlc           0            E..V.......
     cabac           1            E..V.......
     vlc             0            E..V.......
     ac              1            E..V.......
  -aud               <boolean>    E..V....... Include AUD (default false)
  -sei               <flags>      E..V....... Set SEI to include (default identifier+timing+recovery_point)
     identifier                   E..V....... Include encoder version identifier
     timing                       E..V....... Include timing parameters (buffering_period and pic_timing)
     recovery_point               E..V....... Include recovery points where appropriate
  -profile           <int>        E..V....... Set profile (profile_idc and constraint_set*_flag) (from -99 to 65535) (default -99)
     constrained_baseline 578          E..V.......
     main            77           E..V.......
     high            100          E..V.......
  -level             <int>        E..V....... Set level (level_idc) (from -99 to 255) (default -99)
     1               10           E..V.......
     1.1             11           E..V.......
     1.2             12           E..V.......
     1.3             13           E..V.......
     2               20           E..V.......
     2.1             21           E..V.......
     2.2             22           E..V.......
     3               30           E..V.......
     3.1             31           E..V.......
     3.2             32           E..V.......
     4               40           E..V.......
     4.1             41           E..V.......
     4.2             42           E..V.......
     5               50           E..V.......
     5.1             51           E..V.......
     5.2             52           E..V.......
     6               60           E..V.......
     6.1             61           E..V.......
     6.2             62           E..V.......
```

For VAAPI, the private codec option `-sei:v +timing` must be passed to `h264_vaapi`.

(b). For the `h264_qsv` encoder wrapper:

```bash
ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_qsv

Encoder h264_qsv [H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration)]:
    General capabilities: delay hybrid 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: qsv qsv qsv 
    Supported pixel formats: nv12 p010le qsv
h264_qsv encoder AVOptions:
  -async_depth       <int>        E..V....... Maximum processing parallelism (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 4)
  -avbr_accuracy     <int>        E..V....... Accuracy of the AVBR ratecontrol (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -avbr_convergence  <int>        E..V....... Convergence of the AVBR ratecontrol (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -preset            <int>        E..V....... (from 1 to 7) (default medium)
     veryfast        7            E..V.......
     faster          6            E..V.......
     fast            5            E..V.......
     medium          4            E..V.......
     slow            3            E..V.......
     slower          2            E..V.......
     veryslow        1            E..V.......
  -rdo               <int>        E..V....... Enable rate distortion optimization (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -max_frame_size    <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded frame size in bytes (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
  -max_slice_size    <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded slice size in bytes (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
  -bitrate_limit     <int>        E..V....... Toggle bitrate limitations (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -mbbrc             <int>        E..V....... MB level bitrate control (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -extbrc            <int>        E..V....... Extended bitrate control (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -adaptive_i        <int>        E..V....... Adaptive I-frame placement (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -adaptive_b        <int>        E..V....... Adaptive B-frame placement (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -b_strategy        <int>        E..V....... Strategy to choose between I/P/B-frames (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -forced_idr        <boolean>    E..V....... Forcing I frames as IDR frames (default false)
  -low_power         <boolean>    E..V....... enable low power mode(experimental: many limitations by mfx version, BRC modes, etc.) (default false)
  -cavlc             <int>        E..V....... Enable CAVLC (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -idr_interval      <int>        E..V....... Distance (in I-frames) between IDR frames (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -pic_timing_sei    <int>        E..V....... Insert picture timing SEI with pic_struct_syntax element (from 0 to 1) (default 1)
  -single_sei_nal_unit <int>        E..V....... Put all the SEI messages into one NALU (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -max_dec_frame_buffering <int>        E..V....... Maximum number of frames buffered in the DPB (from 0 to 65535) (default 0)
  -look_ahead        <int>        E..V....... Use VBR algorithm with look ahead (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -look_ahead_depth  <int>        E..V....... Depth of look ahead in number frames (from 0 to 100) (default 0)
  -look_ahead_downsampling <int>        E..V....... Downscaling factor for the frames saved for the lookahead analysis (from 0 to 3) (default unknown)
     unknown         0            E..V.......
     auto            0            E..V.......
     off             1            E..V.......
     2x              2            E..V.......
     4x              3            E..V.......
  -int_ref_type      <int>        E..V....... Intra refresh type (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
     none            0            E..V.......
     vertical        1            E..V.......
  -int_ref_cycle_size <int>        E..V....... Number of frames in the intra refresh cycle (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
  -int_ref_qp_delta  <int>        E..V....... QP difference for the refresh MBs (from -32768 to 32767) (default -32768)
  -recovery_point_sei <int>        E..V....... Insert recovery point SEI messages (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -profile           <int>        E..V....... (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default unknown)
     unknown         0            E..V.......
     baseline        66           E..V.......
     main            77           E..V.......
     high            100          E..V.......
  -a53cc             <int>        E..V....... Use A53 Closed Captions (if available) (from 0 to 1) (default 1)
  -aud               <int>        E..V....... Insert the Access Unit Delimiter NAL (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -mfmode            <int>        E..V....... Multi-Frame Mode (from 0 to 2) (default auto)
     off             1            E..V.......
     auto            2            E..V.......
  -repeat_pps        <boolean>    E..V....... repeat pps for every frame (default false)
```

The QSV encoder wrapper requires the private codec option `-pic_timing_sei:v 1` to be set, and this is the default. This can be overridden to disable the same by passing `0` to the aforementioned parameter.

(c). For `h264_nvenc`, this option is [enabled by default](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/4e6638abb4fc176739be021d5e5b3b1bc8de099c).

**Update:**

On the HEVC side, ffmpeg's `hevc_nvenc` wrapper supports it through the private codec option `-s12m_tc` option that must be set to `1` to enable. This is mentioned because of the [work-in-progress support for enhanced RTMP in FFmpeg](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20230406121241.86114-1-lq@chinaffmpeg.org/#76985) that implements HEVC.

Answer (score 1):

To see if incoming stream has the data:

use ffprobe -show_packets rather than -show_frames

```
 "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Producer Reference Time",
                    "wallclock": 104471944699,
                    "wallclock(s)": "104471944699",
                    "flags": 24
                }
```

To see that data ffprobe needs a small mod:

ffprobe.c:2364

```
} else if (sd->type == AV_PKT_DATA_AFD && sd->size > 0) {
    print_int("active_format", *sd->data);
} else if (sd->type == AV_PKT_DATA_PRFT && sd->size > 0) {
    const AVProducerReferenceTime *prop = (AVProducerReferenceTime *)sd->data;
    print_ts("wallclock",prop->wallclock);
    print_int("flags",prop->flags);
```

}