# Gstreamer RTSP Decoding Frame Timestamps

Tags: c++, timestamp, gstreamer, rtsp, decoding

We are decoding RTSP stream frames using Gstreamer in C++. We need to read the frame NTP timestamps, which we think that resides in RTCP packets. After some documentation digging, we found an element called [GstRTPBaseDepayload](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtplib/gstrtpbasedepayload.html?gi-language=c#GstRTPBaseDepayload:stats), which has a property called "stats", which has a field "timestamp", explained as the "last seen RTP timestamp".

Our original pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc port-range=5000-5100 location="rtsp://.." latency=300 is-live=true ! queue ! rtph265depay name=depayer! video/x-h265 , stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! h265parse ! video/x-h265 , stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! appsink name=mysink sync=true`

I named the depay element as `rtph265depay name=dp`, then:

```
    depayer_=gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline_), "dp");
    GstStructure * stat;
    g_object_get((GstRTPBaseDepayload*)depayer_,"stats",stat);
    GType type = gst_structure_get_field_type(stat,"timestamp");
```

It gave an error saying that the stat structure does not have a field, in fact, it did not have any fields. I did not find any example usage of GstRTPBaseDepayload, and the documentation is lacking as always. I would appreciate any guidance regarding the frame timestamps.

Edit:

I also tried to check if depayer_ has a null value:

```
depayer_=gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline_), "dp");
    if(depayer_!=nullptr){
      GstStructure * stat;
      // GstRTPBaseDepayload* depayload;
      g_object_get(depayer_,"stats",stat,NULL);
      if(gst_structure_has_field(stat,"timestamp")){ //this line causes segfault
        guint timestamp;
        gst_structure_get_uint(stat,"timestamp",&timestamp);
      }
    }
```

Neither depayer nor stat object is null, however `gst_structure_has_field(stat,"timestamp")` causes a segfault. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have a stream that I know has a "Producer Reference Time" in it, I can see it using FFProbe, I dug into gstreamer for 10 hours but could not find this (Compiled from source) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167298/how-to-embed-pic-timing-sei-wallclock-timecodes-in-rtmp-streaming/73467279#73467279 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628669/gstreamer-reading-producer-reference-time-from-a-rtsp-h264-stream

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try

```
GstStructure *stat;
// GstRTPBaseDepayload* depayload;
g_object_get(depayer_,"stats",&stat,NULL);
```

notice I used `&stat` in `g_object_get`, not `stat`.

https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/method.Object.get.html

I found an example:
https://github.com/pexip/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-mp4.c#L38-L42